# Update size of Search Icon in headerSearchBarOptions in React Native (Android)

Tags: react-native

```
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerSearchBarOptions: {
        onChangeText: (event) => setSearchValue(event.nativeEvent.text),
        placeholder: "Search",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        searchValue: searchValue,
        hideWhenScrolling: true,
        autoCapitalize: "words",
        shouldShowHintSearchIcon: false,
      },
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```

I want to update the size of the search icon shown through these options. Unfortunately, the official documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/7.x/native-stack-navigator/ provides no props to do that. Is it possible? If not, is there any way to trigger the native search bar through a component in headerRight? Ideally, I would use a custom icon in headerRight to trigger the native search bar.